# How to use LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks and CursorLoader for ORMLite?

Tags: android, android-fragments, ormlite

Recently I started using **ORMLite** for my application. Before I used to use 'ContentProvider' and implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. I would create `CursorLoader` and show the list to user when I have data.

How can I manage that cycle with ORMLite?

I want to create `Cursor` and get notified when `Cursor` is ready.

Thanks

Comment: Try these urls:https://github.com/emmby/ormlite-pr8-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/groupon/dbtest/fragment/Featured.java and https://github.com/campnic/ormlite-android-extras. They are not complete implementations. It gets complicated in public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) { ... }